# Retrieving json data from a single object using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the JSON below:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": null,
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": null
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

What JSON path could I use to retrieve the first element of `book` that contains a `category`, `author`, `price`, and `title` parameter? To be clear, I don't want *any* `category`, `author`, `price`, and `title` parameter -- only those that come from a single book object. Also, the structure of the `book` array varies (i.e. the number and configuration of its elements changes over time) so I can't really hardcode anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want:

$..book[?(@.category && @.author && @.price && @.title)]